# Discord.py - Is there a way to use @commands.has_role('RoleName') to check and see if the person has one of two roles?

Tags: python, discord.py

I know of @commands.has_role('RoleName'), but I was wondering if there was something that would would allow me to do something like @commands.has_roles('RoleName1','RoleName2') and if the person has either one of the two roles, it would still let them use the command.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the list of roles a person has. Using [`member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20roles#discord.Member.roles), you can get all of the specified user's roles.

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    if role in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.send(f"You have the role {role.name}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"You don't have the role {role.name}")
```

[image: Testing this command, it works]

---

There is also [`@commands.has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has%20any%20role#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role). This will require the use of error-handling.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Role One", 805585933641711636) # you can use name or id, both work
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This works")
```

[image: You will need error handling]

This may be one way you can do error-handling.

```py
@test.error
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("You can't do that!")
```

Answer (score 2):

With only one minute googling, you can find your answer on API References. You can use `discord.ext.commands.has_any_role`. For example:

```py
@commands.has_any_role('role1', 'role2')
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('You have the required role.')
```

## Reference

- [`discord.ext.commands.has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role)